# Ошибка на дообучении модели

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, dataclass

Я пытаюсь дообучить модель. Версию lightgbm я обновила до 3.0.0.
Моя модель имеет следующие параметры:

```
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))  
LGBMModel.get_params of LGBMClassifier(bagging_fraction=0.1, bagging_freq=1, boosting_type='rf',
           class_weight=None, colsample_bytree=1, importance_type='split',
           learning_rate=0.5, max_depth=2, metric='custom',
           min_child_samples=20, min_child_weight=0.001, min_split_gain=0.0,
           n_estimators=450, n_jobs=-1, num_leaves=5, objective='binary',
           random_state=501, reg_alpha=3, reg_lambda=0.6, silent=True,
           subsample=0.1, subsample_for_bin=200000, subsample_freq=0)
```

Я пытаюсь ее дообучить и передаю в init_model (я пыталась передать туда файл в формате .txt, .pkl, .sav )

```
mdl_metric = lgbm.LGBMClassifier()    

mdl_metric.fit(
     X_train, y_train,
     eval_set=[(X_train, y_train)],
     early_stopping_rounds=1000,
     verbose=5, 
     init_model=model
     )
```

Но я получаю ошибку:

```
Check failed: (train_data->metadata().init_score()) == (nullptr) at d:\a\1\s\python- 
package\compile\src\boosting\rf.hpp, line 44
```

Comment: У вас модель записана той же версией `lightgbm` и с той же установленной версией `pickle`? Боюсь они там часто меняют форматы.

Comment: В разных, но перезапись модели в новой версии не помогает.

Comment: Ну я написал там в ответе что со случайным лесом так нельзя видимо

Answer (score 0):

```
boosting_type='rf'
```

[Тут пишут](https://github.com/Microsoft/LightGBM/issues/1352), что `Random Forest` не поддерживает продолжение обучения. И это, в общем-то логично, насколько я помню алгоритмы разных методов машинного обучения. Да и вообще как-то странно использовать `LightGBM`, чтобы обучать `Random Forest`. У `LightGBM` есть прекрасные методы бустинга, быстрые и при этом довольно точные. Используйте, например `boosting_type='gbdt'`.